# Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Name'

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a hashtable which contains keys and values like below,

```
$hostVM = [ordered]@{3 = {hostpc-1, hostpc-3, hostpc-5} ; 2 = {hostpc-2,hostpc-4}}
```

Here is my code to read the values from `$jumpHash` hashtable,

```
$esxarray = @(10.91.91.XX7, 10.91.91.XX8)
$vmf = 0
$hostVM.GetEnumerator() | foreach {
    Import-VApp -Source $hostpath -Name $_.Value -DiskStorageFormat Thin -VMHost $esxarray[$vmf] -Datastore $storage
    $vmf = $vmf+1
  }
```

Using GetEnumerator() method I have enumerated all the values in `$hostvm`, but I'm not able to invoke the values from the hashtable to be used in `-Name` parameter and also receiving the below error.

```
Import-VApp : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Name'. Specified method is not 
supported.
At C:\ONTAP_Hashtable.ps1:65 char:45
+     Import-VApp -Source $hostvmpath -Name $_.Value -DiskStorageForm ...
```

Please suggest a way to invoke the values. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a VMWare environment to test the below.

However, the base part of this is all syntactically wrong. If you open this in the ISE/VSCode, or if you scan it with PSCriptAnalyzer, it will show you this.

> • Best Practices for aliases
>
> Best Practice for Using Aliases in PowerShell Scripts
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/best-practice-for-using-aliases-in-powershell-scripts
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-powershell-aliases-best-practices
>
> Why worry about aliases in the first place?
>
> What is the big deal about using aliases anyway? If they make the code
> easier to type, what is the harm in using them in scripts? There are
> two things at work when it comes to a script. The first is that no
> alias is guaranteed to exist—even aliases that are created by Windows
> PowerShell.

```
Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Path .\CannotConvert.ps1

RuleName                            Severity     ScriptName Line  Message                                                     
--------                            --------     ---------- ----  -------                                                     
MissingArgument                     ParseError   CannotConv 1     Missing argument in parameter list.                         
                                                 ert.ps1                                                                      
MissingArgument                     ParseError   CannotConv 1     Missing argument in parameter list.                         
                                                 ert.ps1                                                                      
MissingPropertyName                 ParseError   CannotConv 3     Missing property name after reference operator.             
                                                 ert.ps1                                                                      
PSAvoidUsingCmdletAliases           Warning      CannotConv 5     'foreach' is an alias of 'ForEach-Object'. Alias can        
                                                 ert.ps1          introduce possible problems and make scripts hard to        
                                                                  maintain. Please consider changing alias to its full        
                                                                  content.                                                    
PSUseCompatibleSyntax               Warning      CannotConv 3     The dynamic member invocation syntax '10.91.91.XX7,         
                                                 ert.ps1          10.91.91.XX8' is not available by default in PowerShell     
                                                                  versions 3
```

The ISE, VSCode, have addons/features, to auto-expand aliases. So, you can use them in your dev effort, but on check-ins and production releases, expand them. Interactive command stuff and throw away code is the target use case for them.

You cannot use a hash table, or ForEach this way. Individually or together.

A real good article on the hash table use cases.

> [Everything you wanted to know about hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7)

Check your results at each step and make sure you are getting what you'd expect before moving to the next. Using poor-mans' debug, via PowerShell variable squeezing to assign to a variable and outputting to the screen simultaneously

Yours will error out immediatly:

```
($hostVM = [ordered]@{3 = {hostpc-1, hostpc-3, hostpc-5} ; 2 = {hostpc-2,hostpc-4}})
# Results
<#
At line:1 char:36
+ ($hostVM = [ordered]@{3 = {hostpc-1, hostpc-3, hostpc-5} ; 2 = {hostp ...
+                                    ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:1 char:73
+ ... ordered]@{3 = {hostpc-1, hostpc-3, hostpc-5} ; 2 = {hostpc-2,hostpc-4 ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
#>
```

Vs, doing this:

```
($hostVM = [ordered]@{
    3 = 'hostpc-1, hostpc-3, hostpc-5'
    2 = 'hostpc-2,hostpc-4'
})
# Results
<#
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                     
3                              hostpc-1, hostpc-3, hostpc-5                                                                                                              
2                              hostpc-2,hostpc-4  
#>
```

You cannot use a dotted string in an array the way you are trying. Another article.

> [Everything you wanted to know about arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7)

Same issue as the aforementioned:

```
($esxarray = @(10.91.91.XX7, 10.91.91.XX8))
# Results
<#
At line:1 char:22
+ ($esxarray = @(10.91.91.XX7, 10.91.91.XX8))
+                      ~
Missing property name after reference operator.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingPropertyName
#>
```

Vs doing this:

```
($esxarray = @('10.91.91.XX7', '10.91.91.XX8'))
# Results
<#
10.91.91.XX7
10.91.91.XX8
#>

$vmf = 0

$hostVM.GetEnumerator() | 
foreach {
    Import-VApp -Source $hostpath -Name $_.Value -DiskStorageFormat Thin -VMHost $esxarray[$vmf] -Datastore $storage
    $vmf = $vmf+1
  }
```

***Update***

> ***As per your comment...***

...

If you mean...

```
$hostVM.SomeValue
```

... then no, because, it's a string, not an array. You'd have to do this.

```
((($hostVM.Values)[0]) -split ',')[0]
# Results
<#
hostpc-1
#>
```

Or in your code, you'd have to refactor to this.

```
($hostVM = [ordered]@{
    3 = @('hostpc-1', 'hostpc-3', 'hostpc-5')
    2 = @('hostpc-2','hostpc-4')
})
# Results
<#
Name                           Value
----                           -----
3                              {hostpc-1, hostpc-3, hostpc-5}
2                              {hostpc-2, hostpc-4}
#>

$hostVM.Keys
# Results
<#
3
2
#>

$hostVM.Values
# Results
<#
hostpc-1
hostpc-3
hostpc-5
hostpc-2
hostpc-4
#>

$hostVM[0].GetValue(0)
# Results
<#
hostpc-1
#>

$hostVM[0].GetValue(2)
# Results
<#
hostpc-5
#>
```

Comment: will I be able to read the values of key 3 and key 2 individually? like 'hostpc-1', 'hostpc-3', 'hostpc-5'

Comment: See my update for you. Yet, based on what you posted, you left me to assume stuff, since you were not clear what you were trying to do with that hash table.